# Can Maven generate exe files and mac os x apps?

Tags: java, windows, macos, maven-2

Lets say you created a little Java Desktop app with a jar and some dependencies and possibly a license text file. I know there are plenty of Ant tasks that can generate installers, executables and proper Mac OS X applications including packaging them as ".dmg" files. Examples would be [JarBundler](http://www.informagen.com/JarBundler/) and [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Does similar things exist for Maven?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OSX appbundle plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/osxappbundle-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Is this going to work with Oracle JRE 7? I believe it will pack the bundle in a little bit different way! I used the AppBundler Ant task: https://java.net/projects/appbundler to work with Oracle JRE 7.

Answer (score 4):

I also think launch4j has a maven plugin

Comment: You don't need a maven plugin to use launch4j. Here is an example: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/example-maven-project-setups/tree/master/launch4j-example

Answer (score 4):

To generate a windows executable in a maven build, you can use the launch4j-maven-plugin. I just answered a related question, [Trying to integrate Launch4j in a Maven project using Alakai plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060560/trying-to-integrate-launch4j-in-a-maven-project-using-alakai-plugin), showing how to accomplish that. It's very easy, more than JSmooth, which always had a maven plugin.

Hope it helps!