# Java project to .exe file

Tags: java, maven, installation, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)
>   [Can Maven generate exe files and mac os x apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797209/can-maven-generate-exe-files-and-mac-os-x-apps)

I am building an application in Eclipse. Also I am using Maven to deal with my dependencies. Now I want to deliver my application to users for a testing. They are using Windows machine. I have never done this before and I am not sure how an .exe file can be built together with dependencies which reside on the Maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

Launch4j does a good job of bundling Java applications into executables for Windows distribution.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

It's what I use.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Application Assembler Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to build an executable.